# WooCommerce - get number of different products in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There is [WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/) to show the total number of products in the WooCommerce cart.

But how do you get the number of *different* products?

For example:

- 3 * product A
- 2 * product B

`WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()` would return 5.
But we want to get 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `count(WC()->cart->get_cart());` as `get_cart()` returns an array of items.

[Documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_cart)

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart = $_SESSION['wfcart'];
$count=0
foreach($cart->items as $item){
    $count+= $cart->itemqtys[$item];
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.